# Removing numbers from strings in a Data frame column

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I want to remove numbers from strings in a column, while at the same time keeping numbers that do not have any strings in the same column.
This is how the data looks like;

```
df=
id       description
1         XG154LU
2         4562689
3         556
4         LE896E
5         65KKL4
```

This is how i want the output to look like:

```
id       description
1         XGLU
2         4562689
3         556
4         LEE
5         KKL
```

I used the code below but when i run it it removes all the entries in the description column and replace it with blanks:

```
def clean_text_round1(text):
  text = re.sub('\w*\d\w*', '', text)
  text = re.sub('[‘’“”…]', '', text)
  text = re.sub(r'\n', '', text)
  text = re.sub(r'\r', '', text)
return text

round1 = lambda x: clean_text_round1(x)
df['description'] = df['description'].apply(round1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import numpy as np

df['description'] = np.where(df.description.str.contains('^\d+$'), df.description, df.description.str.replace('\d+', ''))
```

Output:

```
id       description
1         XGLU
2         4562689
3         556
4         LEE
5         KKL
```

Logic:

Look if the string `contains` digits only, if yes, dont do anything and just copy the number as it is. If the string has numbers mixed with string, then `replace` them with black space `''` leaving out only characters without the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it for you.

```
def clean_text_round1(text):
    if type(text) == int:
        return text
    else:
        text = ''.join([i for i in text if not i.isdigit()])
        return text

df['description'] = df['description'].apply(clean_text_round1)
```

Let me know if this works for you. Not sure about the speed performance. You can use regex instead of join.

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert(v):
    # check if the string is composed of not only numbers
    if any([char.isalpha() for char in v]):     
        va = [char for char in v if char.isalpha()]
        va = ''.join(va)
        return va 
    else:        
        return v
# apply() a function for a single column
df['description']= df['description'].apply(convert)
print(df)
```

---

```
id  description
0        XGLU
1     4562689
2         556
3         LEE
4         KKL
```